# How to get the source code of a URL

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsmutableurlrequest

I am not able to get the HTML source code when I try to request this URL: http://www.google.co.in/search?q=search

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/search?q=search"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Webdata : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

The data is always NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/search?q=search"]; 
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
NSLog(@"%@",webData);
```

But if you need to use a NSURLConnection you should use it asynchronously and implement the willSendRequest method to handle redirection.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have updated the question. There are no syntax errors in the code

Comment: @sanjana Google is redirecting, let me best a little bit more.

Answer (score 4):

The simple version:

```
NSURL *TheUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

NSString *webData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl 
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                              error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", webData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can get the data in following ways :-
```

1 .Using NSUrlConnection as [asynchronous reuest](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

```
2. Synchronous NSUrlConnection

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]; 
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 

Simply to check
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://google.com"]; 
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple async solution with GCD:

```
- (void)htmlFromUrl:(NSString *)url handler:(void (^)(NSString *html, NSError *error))handler
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        NSError *error;
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            if (handler)
                handler(html, error);
        });
    });
}
```

then

```
[self htmlFromUrl:@"http://stackoverflow.com" handler:^(NSString *html, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ HTML: %@", error, html);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous fetch of HTML source code, I recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/)

1) Then subclass AFHTTPCLient, for example:

```
//WebClientHelper.h
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface WebClientHelper : AFHTTPClient{

}

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient;

@end

//WebClientHelper.m
#import "WebClientHelper.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

NSString *const gWebBaseURL = @"http://dummyBaseURL.com/";


@implementation WebClientHelper

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient
{
    static WebClientHelper * _sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gWebBaseURL]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    return self;
}
@end
```

2) Request asynchronously HTML source code, put this code in any relevant part

```
NSString *testNewsURL = @"http://whatever.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:testNewsURL];
    NSURLRequest *request  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationHttp =
    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSString *szResponse = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
         NSLog(@"Response: %@", szResponse );
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Operation Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }];

    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operationHttp];
```